# Why does this code generates a cache hit many times?

Tags: c, caching, hardware, memory-access

I understand the concept of cache hit and miss, but somehow I don't really get it on code Examples. The following code should generate many catch Hits, but why? In what part we see that? How we now that this code will finde most of the time the data in the cache?

```
char array[1000]; 
for ( int i=0; i<1000; i++ ){ 
printf("%d ", array[i]); 
}
```

Comment: If you understand how cache works and when there's a hit and miss, it should be obvious. If it is not, you should read more about cache and try to think what it does and what the code does. Draw a cache on paper and play it through.

Comment: since you're accessing the elements in a sequential way and the items are contiguous, cache works at its best because it is designed to do exactly that.

Comment: so Jean, you mean because the data is in a Array it will found it all the time?

Comment: what would be an example of a code that would generate a catch miss many time?

Comment: create a big array, and access the elements very far from each other. 0 index then 10000 then 20000 then 30000, ... or randomly.

Comment: aha ok, so the catch allways goes seqentualy and when we skip an Element then it will genearte a miss when we want to acess an Element that was befor. For example we acessed index 2 then 8 and now we want 4 than by 4 woul be a catch miss. Did i get it now?

Comment: Probably not. Index 4 is in the cache because you accessed index 2 recently.

Comment: So it depence more by distance then by order. But at what distance size it will generate a Miss then?

Comment: This largely depends on your very specific cache implementation. Caches can have different cache line sizes and different mechanisms to find the cache line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is a perfect example of *spatial locality* of reference, because `array[i]` is accessed in continous and forward manner. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Types_of_locality):

> #### Spatial locality
>
> If a particular storage location is referenced at a particular time,
>   then it is likely that nearby memory locations will be referenced in
>   the near future. In this case it is common to attempt to guess the
>   size and shape of the area around the current reference for which it
>   is worthwhile to prepare faster access.

You might also note that `i` variable exhibits *temporal locality*, in which case it's likely that it will be placed by [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) into a CPU register.